# How to get variable from backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, methods, backgroundworker

I have a button that calls a method which calls another method which starts a backgroundworker. The method that calls the backgroundworker

This is the code that calls the first method from the button `string result = SocketSendReceive(host, port, txtConn, txtInput, backgroundWorker1, input, txtUsername, txtPassword, txtIP);`

That calls this method (just the beginning that calls second method):

```
private static string SocketSendReceive(string server, int port, RichTextBox txtConn, TextBox txtInput, BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1, string input, TextBox txtUsername, TextBox txtPassword, TextBox txtIP)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[10024];
        Socket s = null;
        if (txtIP.Text == "")
        {
            s = ConnectSocket(server, port, txtConn, backgroundWorker1);
        } else if (txtIP.Text != "")
        {
            s = ConnectSocketCustom(server, port, txtConn, backgroundWorker1, txtIP);
        }
```

That calls this:

```
private static Socket ConnectSocket(string server, int port, RichTextBox txtConn, BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1)
    {
        Socket s = null;
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

        // Get host related information.
        hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

        // Loop through the AddressList to obtain the supported AddressFamily. This is to avoid
        // an exception that occurs when the host IP Address is not compatible with the address family
        // (typical in the IPv6 case).
        //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(i =>
        //{
            // Connection loop goes here.
        //});
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(s);
        return s;
    }
```

Which calls my backgroundWorker:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "Attempting connection.");
        Socket s = null;
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

        int port;
        if (txtPort.Text == "")
        {
            port = 11000;
        }
        else
        {
            port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text);
            port = int.Parse(txtPort.Text);
        }
        // Get host related information.
        hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);

        // Loop through the AddressList to obtain the supported AddressFamily. This is to avoid
        // an exception that occurs when the host IP Address is not compatible with the address family
        // (typical in the IPv6 case).
        foreach (IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
        {
            IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
            Socket tempSocket =
                new Socket(address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Console.WriteLine(ipe);
            try
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, "Attempting connection.");
                tempSocket.Connect(ipe);
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50, "Connection could not be established.");
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50, "Connection could not be established.");
            }

            if (tempSocket.Connected)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100, "Connection established.");
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                s = tempSocket;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50, "Connection could not be established.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(101, "Connection could not be established.");
    }
```

I need to be able to return the s variable back to the SocketSendReceive method.

**EDIT**

```
private static Socket ConnectSocket(string server, int port, RichTextBox txtConn, BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1)
    {
        Socket s = null;
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

        // Get host related information.
        hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

        // Loop through the AddressList to obtain the supported AddressFamily. This is to avoid
        // an exception that occurs when the host IP Address is not compatible with the address family
        // (typical in the IPv6 case).
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            s = e.Result;
        };
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: You should attach the runworkercompleted event before calling runworkerasync. In the current state, there is a possibility that the completed event may never be called.

Answer (score 0):

In `backgroundWorker1_DoWork()` add `e.Result = s;`

Then in `ConnectSocket()` add

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
   {
       s = e.Result;
   };
```

Comment: When I add that into `ConnectSocket()` it gives me an error that s couldn't be declard because it would give a different meaning to 's'

Comment: Try `s = e.Result as Socket;`. I'm assuming that's just because e.Result is an `object`.

Comment: `RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>` its this s that is giving me the error and I'm assuming it is due to the socket in ConnectSocket() I'm not sure if what I edited is correct

Comment: Oh, right, just change `s` in  `(s, e)` to anything else. Ie `(sender, e)`

Comment: How do I use that to return the socket to SocketSendRecieve()?

Comment: Looking through your code I feel like you need to rearrange some stuff because SocketSendRecieve has to wait for ConnectSocket which has to wait for the background worker. It seems like SocketSendRecieve should be what is async, not just what the background worker is doing.